# Two numbers not adding up

Tags: javascript, math

I'm new to JavaScript, first of all. I'm making a tip calculator, but the numbers are not adding up as expected.

```
  function calculate(bill, tip, people){
    var tip = bill * tip / 100;        
    // Total
    console.log("Total: " + tip + bill / people);
    // Tip
    console.log("Tip: " + tip);

  }
  calculate(100, 5, 1);
```

The output I expected was: `Total: 105`, but I got `Total: 5100`instead. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: First of all, you should clarify your code by naming the variable "tip" to something else, because it shadows the parameter "tip".

Comment: `"Total: " + tip` casts `tip` to a String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're concatenating the numbers as string and not calculating. Put the calculation inside parenthesis and then concatenate:

```js
function calculate(bill, tip, people) {
  var tip = bill * tip / 100;
  // Total
  console.log("Total: " + (tip + bill / people));
  // Tip
  console.log("Tip: " + tip);

}
calculate(100, 5, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   "Total: " + tip + bill / people
```

That will calculate the division first, so it is:

```
 "Total: " + tip + /*value*/
```

Now it is evaluated from left to right, so the string and `tip` get concatenates, which turns `tip` into a string:

```
 "Total: tip" + /*value*/
```

Now string concatenation is done a second time and you end up at:

```
  "Total: tipvalue"
```

to change evaluation order, you can use `(...)` to wrap the operations that have to be done first, in this case `(tip + bill / people)`